# Atom package for HTML support in React JavaScript files

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor

is there a package for Atom text editor that supports HTML autocompletion when writing in React JavaScript files? thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> UPDATE: This is a five year old answer. While still fairly popular, you might find https://atom.io/packages/language-babel to be a solid improvement.

Your best bet is going to be - https://atom.io/packages/react

- Syntax highlighting
- Snippets
- Automatic indentation and folding
- JSX Reformatting
- HTML to JSX conversion
- Autocomplete